# is there any possibility to typedef a type with its method in go?

Tags: go, methods, type-definition

How do I make the below code works? I want to call the Age method with Gents type.

```
package main

type Man struct {
}

func (man *Man) Age() {
}

type Gents Man

func main() {
    var m1 Man
    m1.Age()

    var g1 Gents
    g1.Age()
}
```

Comment: You could *embed* `Man` in `Gents`.

Comment: And if you don't want to change `Gents`, you could also use a type alias: `type Gents = Man`

Comment: @mkopriva, The Gents must be the type definition of man.

Comment: In Go, using a named-type as the definition of a declared type will not re-declare methods of the definition-type on the declared type. Those are the rules as laid out by the language spec. Given the type declaration `type Gents Man`, the only thing that `Gents` and `Man` have in common is their "type structure". Nothing else. They are otherwise two completely distinct types.

Comment: Embedding however, allows you to "promote" the embedded type's fields and methods to the embedding type. Meaning that, given `type Gents struct { Man }`, and `var g1 Gents`, the expression `g1.Age()` becomes valid, although that's likely not what you expect if you're looking for inheritance. https://go.dev/doc/faq#inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to do **inheritance**

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Man struct {
    Year int
}

func (man *Man) Age() int {
    return 2022 - man.Year
}

type Gents struct {
    Man // anonymous field
}

func main() {
    var m1 = Man{
        Year: 1995,
    }
    fmt.Println(m1.Age()) // 27
    var g1 = Gents{
        Man{
            Year: 2002,
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(g1.Age()) // 20
}
```

[go playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/Fpw-04KvOrO)